# Writing a clipboard manager using wxpython?

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets, clipboard

Current state: I have a tray icon, two context menus - one for about/options/exit/etc. on right-click and one on left-click for clipboard management.

One thing I'm not sure of is how to sync clipboard contents - I grasped how to read and write data from/to clipboard, but I don't know how to detect changes(or should I check periodically?).

How would you do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyone please correct me if I am wrong but as far as I think the only way to implement is polling.

I also tried looking at the source code one of the famous clipboard manager http://parcellite.sourceforge.net/.

I found this peace of code in that.

```
  /* Add the daemon loop */
  timeout_id = g_timeout_add_full(G_PRIORITY_LOW,
                                  DAEMON_INTERVAL,
                                  (GSourceFunc)daemon_check,
                                  NULL,
                                  (GDestroyNotify)reset_daemon);
```

And in the header file, DAEMON_INTERVAL is defined as 500. So, it checks after every 500 milliseconds.

Comment: I tried searching a bit more but didn't find any other option than polling it periodically so I guess you're right. Thanks.